# Jquery reveal modal firing as page is opened instead of on click

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm using the jquery reveal modal plugin and it was working fine but all three modals i have suddenly started firing as I open the page, the URL is [mike-griffin.com/index.html](http://mike-griffin.com/index.html) and the script i'm using for this particular modal is as follows:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
<script>
    //code that uses 1.4.4 should be enclosed as follows
    jQuery(function( $ ) {

        $.vegas('slideshow', {
        backgrounds:[
        { src:'img/Background img/Zoe-10-Background.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/Background img/Background2.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'/img/background3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ]
        })('overlay');


 ;$('#main-nav-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});

;$('#sale-nav-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});

;$('#about-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});
    });
</script>
```

I'm not quite sure why this is happening and hopefully it's an easy fix, Thanks anyway!

Comment: So I've figured out a fix for it but would really love if someone could tell what exactly ive done to fix it. I've added (jquery); before the reveal modal script and it seem to have solved the problem but I haven't a clue what (jquery); is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since there has been no more input to this i'll post the answer as what i used as it worked and may help someone with the same issue.

I simply added the following script before the modal script.

```
(jquery);
```

The final script looks as follows...

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
<script>
    //code that uses 1.4.4 should be enclosed as follows
    jQuery(function( $ ) {

        $.vegas('slideshow', {
        backgrounds:[
        { src:'img/Background img/Zoe-10-Background.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/Background img/Background2.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/Background img/Background3.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/Background img/Background4.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/Background img/Background5.jpg', fade:1000 },
        ]
        })('overlay');

    (jquery);

 $('#main-nav-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});

;$('#sale-nav-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});

;$('#about-modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
 animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
 closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
 dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
});
    });
</script>
```